# Angular How to add a third party ui component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have run through the tour of heroes angular tutorial. 
Now I am striking out on my own. But have stumbled at the first hurdle!

How do I add a third party UI component?

I simply want to add a slider (https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider) to a page.
I have searched high and low but cannot find an example of how I do this in a typescript/angular-cli world?

I have added the the package 
npm i angularjs-slider --save

How do I add it to an angular typescript component file and html?

Comment: This component is for AngularJS. You are using Angular which shares only a common name.

Comment: Kindly go through complete readme file. Its having complete steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are working with Angular 2+, but here you are referencing to AngularJS (v1) component. Angular 2+ and AngularJS are not compatible.